# How to write a simple and concise WDM driver custom interfaces in Windows?

Tags: windows

I have two WDM bus drivers: one (**busA**) is acting as parent and the other(**busB**) as child which then enumerates its children. I want to collect some info about busB's children in a list, and save it in busB's parent bus busA.

Later, after some events on busB, I want to collect the saved info from busA into busB.

After some online research I came to know that the way we achieve it is by defining custom interfaces. Unfortunately, all of the explanations are theoretical, and I don't find any code sample to start with. I tried many times on my own but all are giving m bug-checks.

How can I use these custom interfaces to achieve my goal?